# How to pass nested array in a postman automation test script

Tags: json, automation, postman, postman-collection-runner

I'm creating test automation scripts through postman. I want to pass a nested array in postman body

```
{
   "fruit":{{fruit}},
   "Vehicles":[
      {
         "car":{{car}},
         "bike":{{bike}}
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to pass the vehicles array.

When I executed the APIs I get these vehicles as a empty variables. data is not passing

The Response body as follows

```
{
   "fruit":"mango",
   "Vehicles":[
      {
         "car":{{car}},
         "bike":{{bike}}
      }
   ]
}
```

The external json data file

```
[
   {
      "fruit":"mango",
      "Vehicles":[
         {
            "car":"BMW",
            "bike":"YAMAHA"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I'm executing this with postman collection runner and data inside the nested array is not passing.

Comment: Really, don't understand the question. Are you trying to read data from external data file?

Comment: Yes @lucas-nguyen-17

Comment: I think you got it wrong. Read this article https://blog.postman.com/using-csv-and-json-files-in-the-postman-collection-runner/ then edit your json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request body is not valid JSON, after the values from the file have been inserted. You don't have quotation marks araound the values.

Try this:

```
{
   "fruit":"{{fruit}}",
   "Vehicles":[
      {
         "car":"{{car}}",
         "bike":"{{bike}}"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: This is worked for me thanks:)